# @New annotation does not work

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

I try whether the @New annotation of CDI works - and it seems it does not.

In my application I created such class:

```
package pl.piotrek;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
public class DateFactory {
    public @Produces @SessionScoped Date produceDate() {
        return new Date((long)(Math.random() * 2000000000000L));
    }
}
```

Then I try to use it in my servlet:

```
package pl.piotrek;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.enterprise.inject.New;
@WebServlet("/HelloWorld")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @New @Inject
    private Date d1;
    @New @Inject
    private Date d2;
    @New @Inject
    private Date d3;
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
        writer.println(d1 + "\n" + d2 + "\n" + d3);
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

I expected that the servlet will print out three different dates - I annotated the injections with @New annotation - but it prints three same dates, like that:

```
Sat Feb 07 07:53:36 CET 2015
Sat Feb 07 07:53:36 CET 2015
Sat Feb 07 07:53:36 CET 2015
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

short answer: remove the `@New` and the `@SessionScoped`

Comment: A short explanation is worth it: Using `@New` completely skips the producer and creates a plain new instance of Data object - hence all objects will point to the current data, although they are not equal. `@SessionScoped` is causing that within a single session, you will get always the same random object created in the producer. The scope should be unspecified or `@Dependent` in order to generate a new object everytime.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `@SessionScoped` from the producer method. The returned `Date` is bound to the session and won't be called again.

Comment: The fact that the returned date is not a random one (as coded in the producer) but the exact date of the question doesn't seem a strange coincidence to you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're expecting with the `@New` qualifier (remember it was deprecated in CDI 1.1). Reading the [corresponding section the spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#new) could be useful.

Anyway, `@New` is related to Managed Bean and Session Beans (EJB) not producers. The spec states

> Note that this second bean exists - and may be enabled and available
>   for injection - even if the first bean is disabled, as defined by
>   Enabled and disabled beans, or if the bean class is deployed outside
>   of a bean archive, as defined in Bean archives, and is therefore not
>   discovered during the bean discovery process defined in Packaging and
>   deployment. The container discovers @New qualified beans by inspecting
>   injection points of other enabled beans.

So when you write

```
@New @Inject
private Date d1;
```

your producer is not used, it's the `Date` class that is used. Reason why you have always the current date.

Answer (score -1):

With the @New annotation CDI creates simply a new instance of the class defined with the value of the @New annotation. if the value is omitted, then the type of the declared injection point is taken.

Without @New annotation CDI creates a proxy instance instead of the real instance. now with @New instance there is no proxy available because only a new() instance is requested. therefor is no need to call a producer method.. with @New the @Produces annotation is not called.

example code:

```
package pl.piotrek;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.enterprise.inject.New;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.jglue.cdiunit.CdiRunner;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(CdiRunner.class)
public class AtNewAndProducerTest {

    @Produces
    public Date produceDate() {
        return new Date((long)(Math.random() * 2000000000000L));
    }

    @New @Inject
    private Date d1;

    @New @Inject
    private Date d2;

    @New @Inject
    private Date d3;

    @Inject
    private Date d4;

    @Inject
    private Date d5;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(d1);
        System.out.println(d2);
        System.out.println(d3);
        System.out.println(d4);
        System.out.println(d5);

        // will output something like this:
        // Sat Feb 07 13:16:05 CET 2015
        // Sat Feb 07 13:16:05 CET 2015
        // Sat Feb 07 13:16:05 CET 2015
        // Mon Sep 19 12:31:29 CEST 2005
        // Sat Aug 14 21:51:06 CEST 1999
    }

}
```

you can find this example on GitHub:
https://github.com/StefanHeimberg/stackoverflow-28379562

Comment: We try to make the CDI spec as easy to read as possible. So please take a moment to read http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#new and check my answer.